# No color highlight in Eclipse in some files

Tags: java, eclipse

In a workspace with several projects, **I see correctly all the text markup in all files except one**, where there is only the markup for specifiers, types and strings.

What I have already tried:

- Check if the file is opened with the text editor instead of the Java editor. It's not. **The file is opened with the Java Editor**.
- Restart Eclipse.
- Clean the project.

The problem persists.

The problem:
[image]

What I expect:
[image]

Any help will be highly appreciated and voted.

Comment: Did you try to clean the project?

Comment: Yes I did, it have not solved the problem.

Comment: Can you show the project structure for that second file? It's only shown for the first one.

Comment: Yes, I have just changed the screenshot to show the structure of the project where the markup works as desired.

Comment: Does the first one have a populated Outline view? You've said it's open in the Java Editor, but it really does look otherwise--line comments are a different color altogether.

Comment: Hi @nitind, yes it has a populated outline view. I have updated the image to show the outline. You will see that eclipse show several errors in the errors log that I've not been able to solve. This is an imported project and when first imported the markup was correct on this file. Reimporting the project does not solve the issue.

Comment: Interesting. Are you using a JRE that was included with Eclipse? If so, can you try running Eclipse with a different one? The log output makes me think there's some kind of packaging bug with it.

Comment: Ok, I haven't tough that it could be a JRE related problem. I'm going to try what you suggest. Lets see what happens... Thanks!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The *Error Log* view shows that you use a JRE from [Eclipse JustJ](https://www.eclipse.org/justj/) to run your Eclipse.

The problem is that you have a **minimal instead of a complete** JDK installed.

Alternatively, you can [specify the Java 11 or higher VM  in the `eclipse.ini` to run Eclipse](https://wiki.eclipse.org/Eclipse.ini#Specifying_the_JVM).

The *JustJ OpenJDK Hotspot JRE Minimal (Stripped)* is sufficient to run the Eclipse Installer and the Eclipse platform, but not to run the Eclipse Java IDE you have without errors.

*Minimal* means that only those system library modules are included that are required by the Eclipse platform and *Complete* means the full system library.

Comment: Thanks @howlger. I have JDK 15 installed in my computer. Is it possible that somehow Eclipse is not fining the path to the JDK? I have already included it in the PATH environment variables.

Comment: You also have a JDK 14 installed into Eclipse which is currently used. To change that, you have to edit the `eclipse.ini` for that: https://wiki.eclipse.org/Eclipse.ini#Specifying_the_JVM (or uninstall the JustJ JDK).

Comment: I uninstalled the all JDK versions installed, reinstalled JDK 15 and reconfigured the path. After that It seems everything works fine. Thank you all for you effort!