# Eclipse 4.17.0 - Cannot open Eclipse Marketplace - NullPointerException

Tags: eclipse, nullpointerexception, eclipse-marketplace

After upgrading to Eclipse 4.17 running Eclipse Marketplace results in an NPE.

Marketplace 1.8.5v20200902-1804

Running with Java 14

Any advise please.

This is the error from the dialog box...

> Cannot open Eclipse Marketplace
> Cannot install remote marketplace locations
> java.lang.NullPointerException

This is from the log file...

```
java.lang.NullPointerException
at org.eclipse.epp.mpc.ui.CatalogDescriptor.imageDescriptorForUrl(CatalogDescriptor.java:106)
at org.eclipse.epp.mpc.ui.CatalogDescriptor.<init>(CatalogDescriptor.java:87)
at org.eclipse.epp.internal.mpc.ui.commands.AbstractMarketplaceWizardCommand.installRemoteCatalogs(AbstractMarketplaceWizardCommand.java:205)
at org.eclipse.epp.internal.mpc.ui.commands.AbstractMarketplaceWizardCommand.createConfiguration(AbstractMarketplaceWizardCommand.java:92)
at org.eclipse.epp.internal.mpc.ui.commands.MarketplaceWizardCommand.createConfiguration(MarketplaceWizardCommand.java:64)
at org.eclipse.epp.internal.mpc.ui.commands.AbstractMarketplaceWizardCommand.execute(AbstractMarketplaceWizardCommand.java:67)
```

Comment: What Eclipse Marketplace Client version do you have (see _Help > About Eclipse IDE: Installation Details_ and enter `Marketplace` in the search field at the top). Which Java exactly do you use to run Eclipse? What's in the error log?

Comment: Marketplace 1.8.5v20200902-1804, Java 14, the stack trace above is from the log

Comment: Which Java 14 exactly ([make sure it's not this issue](https://stackoverflow.com/a/63955520/6505250))? Delete the log, reproduce the issue and add the whole log to your question, not only the stack trace.

Comment: I am having the same error running Eclipse 4.18 and Marketplace Client 1.9.0.v20201125-0811. Java 11 since Cloud Tools for Eclipse plugin doesn't work with newer versions.

Comment: Bug is back in Marketplace Client 1.9.0.v20201125-0811

Comment: @Darac Where is the bug report? How can this be reproduced?

Answer (score 2):

Also stumbled upon this error with my Eclipse 4.18 and the above mentioned Marketplace Client 1.9.0.v20201125-0811.

Solved this by updating the Marketplace Client manually (-> Install New Software...) with the following update site: http://download.eclipse.org/mpc/drops/1.9.0/v20210108-0835/

So the (currently) most recent version worked fine for me.

Answer (score 0):

This was resolved with the release of MarketPlace 1.8.5v20201009-0749