# Eclipse project built issue due to jre path

Tags: java, eclipse

I am facing the below error in eclipse

**The project was not built due to "Failed to init ct.sym for C:\Users\ljoseph\AppData\Local\Temp\eoi2373.tmp\plugins\org.eclipse.justj.openjdk.hotspot.jre.minimal.stripped.win32.x86_64_14.0.2.v20200815-0932\jre\lib\jrt-fs.jar". Fix the problem, then try refreshing this project and building it since it may be inconsistent Introduction Unknown Java Problem**

I tried by uninstalling jdk and installed again. Still facing the same issue.

jre is not available in Java folder.

Comment: What Eclipse version are you trying to run? What java version did you install? Did you install the JRE or the JDK?

Comment: See https://stackoverflow.com/a/63955520/6505250 Could you please tell the exact steps to get there? Did you use the Eclipse Installer?