# java error in eclipse "The project was not built due to.."

Tags: java, eclipse

i installed java and eclipse, but i keep getting this error.
(environment variables changed ,java -version / javac -version checked from cmd)
after that what i did is:
changing java version from 10 to 15(reinstall)
reinstall eclipse several times

what should i do next?

eclipse: Eclipse IDE 2020‑09
java: jdk-13.0.2_windows-x64

**
The project was not built due to "Failed to init ct.sym for C:\Users\mirei\AppData\Local\Temp\eoiE4ED.tmp\plugins\org.eclipse.justj.openjdk.hotspot.jre.minimal.stripped.win32.x86_64_14.0.2.v20200815-0932\jre\lib\jrt-fs.jar". Fix the problem, then try refreshing this project and building it since it may be inconsistent
**

Comment: See [this answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/63955520/2670892). You need to edit the eclipse.ini to specify a full Java instead of the very minimal version you are currently using.

Comment: thank you so much bro, you saved me. by the way, what i found out was deleting default jre and add jdk(version that i have)instead. could you tell me what is diffrence between these two way?

Answer (score 3):

Please open the project properties: >>  right-click on that project. >> Last option for Properties >> choose Java Compiler section, >>  in the Use '--release' option box, uncheck that box. Select Apply and Yes to rebuild the project.