# Eclipse project build failed to init ct.sym for jre/lib/jrt-fs.jar

Tags: java, eclipse

This has been a nightmare lately to setup Eclipse 2020 for some demo servlet.

The project structure is:

[image: File structure]

The demo servlet dies with "Http Status 500 - Error instantiating servlet class" with the root cause as "java.lang.ClassNotFoundException".

There is a red cross beside my project and an error log stating:

> Failed to init ct.sym for C:\Users\Pratyay Mukherjee\AppData\Local\Temp\eoi8BAC.tmp\plugins\org.eclipse.justj.openjdk.hotspot.jre.minimal.stripped.win32.x86_64_14.0.2.v20200815-0932\jre\lib\jrt-fs.jar

I have tried rebuilding the project again and again as that is the solution for everything wrong with Eclipse. What is going wrong in my project and how can I get the servlet to work without errors?

Comment: I had also tried demoapp.AddServlet as well in web.xml file.

Comment: See https://stackoverflow.com/a/63955520/6505250

Comment: which error are you addressing with this? The red cross beside project or the ClassNotFoundException

Comment: It addresses the root error of running Eclipse with the wrong JRE (with an incomplete system library) which can cause multiple subsequent errors (have a look at the Eclipse source code, if you are really interested in what is used where from the system library). Did an error remain after you fixed it?

Comment: I had downloaded jdk from https://www.oracle.com/java/technologies/javase-jdk15-downloads.html . The primary reason for downloading only JDK is that both JRE and JDK can be used to run Eclipse. While downloading JDK there was no prompt for any minimal download.

Comment: Java 15 is too new, you need [this plugin](https://marketplace.eclipse.org/content/java-15-support-eclipse-2020-09-417) for it and not everything might work yet. Better use Java 11 which has LTS and which you can e.g. downloaded from [AdoptOpenJDK](https://adoptopenjdk.net/) (Oracle provides JDKs only and there are still free to use but not free anymore to bundle as part of your product).

Comment: Nope same error. The description says : "The server encountered an internal error that prevented it from fulfilling this request." just as before along with whatever error I had mentioned before. I downloaded Java 11 with OpenJ9, re-installed Eclipse IDE 2020-09, and set the AdoptOpenJDK RE at the time of installation. Still no luck

Comment: thanks for your help. I solved the problem. I was using some minimal old JRE that I had installed previously.

Answer (score 1):

The following fixed the issue for me.

- Installed OpenJDK 15.0.1 on my computer.
- In Window/Preferences/Java/Installed JREs, I added a link to the new Java version (and named it "openjdk-15" to help identify it). I unchecked the existing jre and selected the newly installed.
- I started a NEW PROJECT, and for the JRE, made sure to select the new default jre.
- I copied over the source code of the failing project into the new project.

See https://www.eclipse.org/forums/index.php/t/1106241/