# Could not find or load main class in Eclipse

Tags: java, eclipse

I created a new java project in eclipse. This is the first time I am using it.
After creating java files.
I tried running a java file by `right clicking->Run As-> Java Application`
It showed the error :

```
Error: Could not find or load main class ISBN
Caused by: java.lang.ClassNotFoundException: ISBN
```

[image: Project-screenshot]
What could be the reason for this error? How do I fix it?

Comment: One (or more) of your Java files needs to have a `public static void main(...)` method, which is an entry point.  Double check your code for this.

Comment: You try to run your code with a Java where some parts of the system library has been removed (see _Console_ header line `minimal.stripped`). This is probably because you installed Eclipse incorrectly via the Eclipse Installer. See also https://stackoverflow.com/a/63955520/6505250

Comment: what will be the correct way to install eclipse. It didn't ask me anything. Should I reinstall it rather than fixing this issue? It was a fresh install. This is weird. I have used Intellij that works so smoothly. Probably I need to download `Eclipse IDE for Java Developers
` I instead downloaded the eclipse on the downloads page and then it asked me to download the java one. Should be same but I will give the other one a try

Comment: Yes, a fresh install, but maybe with an outdated Eclipse Installer? And there was a dropdown list where you chose it. You might install the _JustJ OpenJDK Hotspot JRE Complete_ from the update site [`https://download.eclipse.org/justj/jres/15/updates/release/latest`](https://download.eclipse.org/justj/jres/15/updates/release/latest) or reinstall using the current Eclipse Installer or directly an IDE package.