# Error while creating a dynamic web project in error

Tags: java, eclipse

I installed eclipse version 4.18.0 and configured with tomcat V9.0. When i try to create a new dynamic web project i am getting a error like this....

**The project was not built due to "Failed to init ct.sym for C:\Users\teja reddy\AppData\Local\Temp\eoi7454.tmp\plugins\org.eclipse.justj.openjdk.hotspot.jre.minimal.stripped.win32.x86_64_15.0.1.v20201027-0507\jre\lib\jrt-fs.jar". Fix the problem, then try refreshing this project and building it since it may be inconsistent**

I tried to reinstall the eclipse several times but that is not working. Please help me to solve this issue.

Comment: Does this answer your question? [The project was not built due to "Failed to init ct.sym for C:\Program Files\Java\jre-10.0.2\lib\jrt-fs.jar" in IDE Eclipse](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/63446925/the-project-was-not-built-due-to-failed-to-init-ct-sym-for-c-program-files-jav)

Comment: The problem here is the used minimal JustJ JRE that does not contain the full system library. It should also not be used to run the Eclipse IDE. For details see: https://stackoverflow.com/a/63955520/6505250 (and my [comments here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/65881449/could-not-find-or-load-main-class-in-eclipse#comment116482564_65881449)).