# i am having problem with swing in eclipse

Tags: java, eclipse, swing

```
    package letsgo;
    import javax.swing.JOptionPane;
    class prac50_gui {
    public static void main(String args[])
    {
        String first=JOptionPane.showInputDialog("Enter the first Number:");
        String second=JOptionPane.showInputDialog("ENter the second Number:");
        int num1=Integer.parseInt(first);
        int num2=Integer.parseInt(second);
        int sum =num1 +num2; 
        JOptionPane.showMessageDialog(null, "The total is :"+sum,"the title",JOptionPane.PLAIN_MESSAGE);
    }
    }
```

[error message while using swing and JOPtionPane in eclipse, java . compiler is latest and jdk version too](https://i.stack.imgur.com/7vVZx.png)

Comment: don't post an external link to an "error message", put all the relevant information in the question itself. It seems to me these ' 's shouldn't be there: "the `title",JOptionPane.PLAIN_MESSAGE);` (before title and after the ;)

Comment: @Stultuske that's a copy-paste error. They are not present in the screenshot

Comment: Eclipse is using the very minimal version of Java included with Eclipse. This is enough to run Eclipse but does not include things like Swing. You need to install a full Java and tell Eclipse to use it to run programs.

Comment: See https://stackoverflow.com/a/63955520/6505250

Comment: @greg-449 The minimal JustJ JRE is also not enough to run the Eclipse Java IDE (and I guess also not enough for the other IDE packages), only enough to run the Eclipse Installer.

Comment: ive added swing as well as windows builder but still receiving Exception in thread "main" java.lang.UnsatisfiedLinkError: no awt in system library path:

Comment: Exception in thread "main" java.lang.UnsatisfiedLinkError: no awt in system library path: C:\Users\user\AppData\Local\Temp\eoi7E04.tmp\plugins\org.eclipse.justj.openjdk.hotspot.jre.minimal.stripped.win32.x86_64_15.0.1.v20201027-0507\jre\bin
 at java.base/java.lang.ClassLoader.loadLibrary(Unknown Source)