# Not able to build project in Spring MVC

Tags: java, eclipse, spring-mvc

I have made some changes in my project after creating it. I updated the project facets then when I am trying to rebuild the same project then it is giving me error like:

> The project was not built due to "Failed to init ct.sym for
> C:\Users\AppData\Local\Temp\eoi629D.tmp\plugins\org.eclipse.justj.openjdk.hotspot.jre.minimal.stripped.win32.x86_64_15.0.1.v20201027-0507\jre\lib\jrt-fs.jar".
> Fix the problem, then try refreshing this project and building it
> since it may be inconsistent Spring   MVC Unknown Java Problem

Comment: You are using the very minimal Java  that Eclipse uses to install. You need to tell Eclipse about a full Java installation.

Comment: Thankyou for reply but I don't know how to do that. Can you please help me to do that?

Comment: See [this answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/63955520/2670892)